# InkWell splash color effect not showing when adding Navigator.push Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design

I'm trying to implement a button that calls another page when it is tapped.

I'm wrapping a container with the `inkWell` widget that has a splash color effect and the `onTap (){}`.
The button shows the splash color effect with the `onTap (){}` empty however when I add a `Navigator.push..` to call another page, the splash color effect disappears.

Any idea about how to solve this?

**This is the code**

```
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 11),
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: InkWell(
                  splashColor: Colors.grey,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageTransition(
                        type: PageTransitionType.downToUp,
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                        child: ProfileProduct(
                          imageUrl: widget.reviews.imageUrl,
                          cost: widget.reviews.cost,
                          name: widget.reviews.userName,
                          address: widget.reviews.address,
                          brand: widget.reviews.brand,
                          productName: widget.reviews.productName,
                          userImage: widget.reviews.userImage,
                          currentUserId: widget.reviews.authorId,
                          cSrateStars: widget.reviews.cSrateStars,
                          easyPurchaseRateStars:
                              widget.reviews.easyPurchaseRateStars,
                          envioDiasRateStars: widget.reviews.envioDiasRateStars,
                          totalRate: widget.reviews.totalRate,
                          recomendation: widget.reviews.recomendation,
                          businessName: widget.reviews.businessName,
                          fecha: widget.reviews.timestamp,
                          videoLink: widget.reviews.videoLink,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Container(
//                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    height: 280,
                    width: 190,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 2),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 12.0,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                backgroundImage: widget
                                        .reviews.userImage.isEmpty
                                    ? AssetImage(
                                        'assets/images/user_placeholder.jpg')
                                    : CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                        widget.reviews.userImage),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 0.0),
                              Text(
                                widget.reviews.userName,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                              ),
                              IconButton(
//                            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                icon: _isLiked
                                    ? Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      )
                                    : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                iconSize: 15.0,
                                onPressed: _likePost,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        AutoSizeText(
                          widget.reviews.productName,
                          maxLines: 4,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 3.0),
                        RatingStars(widget: widget),
                        SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                        AutoSizeText(
                          '$costos',
                          maxLines: 4,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 3.0),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            widget.reviews.comments,
                            maxLines: 3,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
//                    SizedBox(height: 3.0),
                        AutoSizeText(
                          'See More...',
                          maxLines: 4,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${_likeCount.toString()} likes',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same problem and realised the "NewPage()" loads before the Inkwell splash is shown.  I did a small **hack** by delaying the Navigator.push by 300 milliseconds. It seems to work.

```
InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        onTap: () {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage()));
          });
        },
child:Somewidget,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have an onTap: in the inkwell else the splash will not appear even after wrapping it with material

Comment: After hours of messing with things, this was the piece of info I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `InkWell` widget must have a `Material` widget as an ancestor. The `Material` widget is where the ink reactions are actually painted. This matches the material design premise wherein the Material is what is actually reacting to touches by spreading ink.

**The ink splashes aren't visible!**

If there is an opaque graphic, e.g. painted using a `Container, Image, or DecoratedBox`, between the Material widget and the InkWell widget, then the splash won't be visible because it will be under the opaque graphic. This is because ink splashes draw on the underlying Material itself, as if the ink was spreading inside the material.

The Ink widget can be used as a replacement for `Image, Container, or DecoratedBox` to ensure that the image or decoration also paints in the Material itself, below the ink.

editing you widget as per description above

```
Material(
          child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("tapped me");
        },
        splashColor: Colors.grey,....
```

Comment: Actually I do have Material as ancestor per my code above and the splash is visible with not problem, the issue as mention above is when I add navigator.push (to call another page)inside the on tap, when I do that the splash just desapears.

Comment: Your solution does not fix my issue, actually, I do have Material as ancestor per my code above and the splash is visible with no problem, the issue as mention above is when I add navigator.push (to call another page)inside the onTap, when I do that the splash just desapears. In short words, The splash effect is visible as I want as long as the navigator is not inside the onTap and that's the issue, I want the splash effect visible no matter what's inside the onTap, any solutions?

Comment: Also, if you check my code I'm not adding any color to the container that may cover the splash effect, the material is the one that has the color white and that's why the splash is visible as I want but the issue is weird because I dont know what navigator.push inside the onTap has anything to do with the splash effect

Comment: Sure I'll look at it in a few

Comment: @AlfonsoAngulo did you solve this pproblem? I am faced by the same.